# Google Apis V2 html mime/type

Tags: c#, html, upload, google-api

I upload doc,xls files but i dont understand how upload html files. This code upload file but dont preview file. Its say- "We apologize Preview not available". Whats mime type i must set ?

```
 if (extension == ".htm" || extension == ".html")
                    {

                        File body = new File();
                        body.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item); 
                        //body.Description = "A test document";
                        body.MimeType = "text/HTML";
                        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(item);
                        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

                        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream,
                                                                                       "application/vnd.google-apps.file");
                        request.Convert = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems uploading files using the Gmail API. I don't know if the Files API works the same but, you could try encoding the byteArray before you call the Insert method. Implement these methods:

```
protected static string Base64ForUrlEncode(string str)
        {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)).TrimEnd('='));
            result.Replace('+', '-');
            result.Replace('/', '_');
            return result.ToString();
        }

protected static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Then, call it before the Insert method:

```
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(item);
string base64 = Base64ForUrlEncode(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray));
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(GetBytes(base64));
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "application/vnd.google-apps.file");
```

You could also try to set the mime type to "text/html", in lowercase letters.

Comment: what is the email? what is contain?

Comment: Sorry I've copied from my implementation. In your case is not `email` is `byteArray`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: and what you set in "myme/type"?

Comment: Like I said in the answer: "text/html", in lowercase.

Comment: its get url, but i can view it only in DocViewer

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your comment. What do you mean with "its get url"?